# Is there a name for this integer linear optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have an integer linear programming problem of the form:

$$\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr} \min \tr WX$$ subject to:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_j X_{ij} < c_i && \forall i \\
\sum_i X_{ij} = 1 && \forall j \\
X_{ij} \in \{0,1\} && \forall i,j
\end{align}$$

I'm sure this is probably a common problem that's been well studied, but I can't find the name for it.  Does anyone know?

Comment: All of the variables are either 0 or 1.

Comment: Ahh i misread the statement. Thought it was must be in the interval of 0 to 1. my bad.

Answer (score 3):

This is a minimum cost network flow problem. Construct the network as follows.  You haven't specified the ranges for $i$ and $j$, but I'll assume that we $i=1, 2, \ldots, m$ and $j=1, 2, \ldots, n$.

- A source node $s$ sourcing $n$ units of flow.
- $m$ nodes $u_{i}$, $i=1, 2, \ldots, m$.
- Arcs from $s$ to $u_{i}$ with capacity $c_{i}$ for $i=1, 2, \ldots m$.
- $n$ nodes $v_{j}$, $j=1, 2, \ldots, n$.
- Arcs $(u_{i},v_{j})$, for all $i,j$, each with capacity 1.
- A node $t$ that is a sink for $n$ units of flow.
- Arcs from $v_{j}$ to $t$ with capcity one for $j=1, 2, \ldots, n$.
- Weights $W_{j,i}$ on the arcs from $u_{i}$ to $v_{j}$.  Weights of 0 on the remaining arcs.

Any feasible flow on this graph corresponds to a solution of the LP relaxation of the above problem.  Since the constraint matrix of the LP is totally-unimodular, any optimal BFS has integer values for all of the variables $X_{i,j}$.

You can solve this problem using the simplex method or by using a specialized algorithm for the minimum cost network flow problem.